# AudioKit v5: Metronome Example

Tags: swift, xcode, audiokit

In the latest AudioKit v5 there is still the Metronome example missing, but i guess that is easy to do, when you know what you are doing. As I'm just starting with AudioKit is there any advice how to do that? As I understood one has to setup a MidiSequencer and assign an audio file to it, right? How would i do that?